# R+shiny: Read an input variable from a non-reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)

foo <- function(a, b){
  a*b*input$ni
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("ni", label = "in", value = 3),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText(foo(a = 2, b = 4))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Running this results in the error `object 'input' not found`. The `foo` function does not know about the shiny inputs because it's written outside the shiny functions and it's not a reactive function.

How can I make it work? Because of how my code is built (beyond this MWE), I need that the function `foo` only takes the parameters `a` and `b` and none else. That is, the input cannot be passed into it as an argument. It also needs sit outside of the server function.

Is there a way to make it take the input variable from the shiny environment somehow?

Comment: Wondering why `foo` shouldn't take an extra `input` argument which would keep this very simple.

Comment: @Waldi that would indeed be a good solution, except that in this case I am not allowed to change the arguments passed into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the function arguments you can make use of global assignment operator (`<<-`) so that the variable is available outside the scope of function.

```
library(shiny)

foo <- function(a, b){
  a*b*ni
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("ni", label = "in", value = 3),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$out <- renderText({
    ni <<- input$ni
    foo(a = 2, b = 4)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]